# Which is this multi vendor panel in magento?

Tags: magento-1.7, multi-vendor

I want to extend magento to market place. I come across one vendor panel for magento
You can video here
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6U660bv3ACg

Anybbody know which marketplace / extension is this?

[image]

Comment: Really really bad idea, technically you can do it but it is a road to nowhere. Magento is not designed to allow multi-vendor data entry, yes you can buy extensions and they will work if you are happy with revenue in the $10s thousands, above that you will get no further. Most are custom build, we use an external tool that auto-syncs to Magento and is the vendor portal, not something you average site can do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a very well-styled [Unirgy Udropship](http://www.unirgy.com/products/udropship/). Alternatively they may have Udropship Installed alongside [Umarketplace](http://www.unirgy.com//products/umarketplace/magento-multi-vendor-marketplace), thus the `marketplace` route.

[image]